# Typeorm relationships - save by id

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I've been kinda confused by the relationships as I'm used to save relationship by id, while docs and examples I found suggest to get the entire object and use that instead (Isn't this strange???)

I found this on github addressing this issue ( https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/447 ) , where they suggest to use an object with just the id property, but it's from 2017. Is that a good way to do it ? And is it still the only way to do it ? (I find it pretty lame tbh)

```js
async create( @Body() product: Product) {
    product.category = <any>{ id: product.category };
    return { payload: await this.repository.persist(product) };
}
```

Another one suggested to name the column as categoryId and it would work as expected (with id instead of object) but WHY? What does the name have to do with that ??

```js
@Entity()
class Product {

     @Column({ type: "int", nullable: true })
     categoryId: number;

     @ManyToOne(type => Category)
     @JoinColumn({ name: "categoryId" })
     category: Category;

}
```

I'm just confused, help ^_^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Isn't this strange???

Depends how you think about it, but yeah, I also like being able to just set the id, and not fetch the entire related entity.

> Is that a good way to do it ? And is it still the only way to do it ?

I am also in the process of figuring out typeorm. What I found out is that you can do:

```
product.category = <any>3;
// or
product['category' as any] = 3;
repository.save(product) // I don't know how you have the persist() method.
```

and, in your case, the product.categoryId column will be set to 3. If categoryId is a foreign key and you set a non-existing id, you will get a foreign key error, like you should.

But this way ts will still think that `product.category` is of type `Category`. You can also specify the `category` property as a `Category | number`. But then you would have to do type checks everywhere which is annoying. I've tested this a bit, but I'm not sure if this will cause some unsuspecting bugs.

> What does the name have to do with that ??

Well the option you provided is to define 2 properties: `category` which is a relation, and `categoryId` which is the column. The property `categoryId` should be named like the column in the table, but you can also pass the `name: 'actual_name'` in the `@Column` decorator. I don't know what happens if you set both `columnId` and the `column` properties with different ids.

Comment: What do you mean by "you can just do product.category = 3" ? I get a type error on that, do you mean that it works even if it gives a type error?

Comment: You are right. I was testing my code in node REPL and it worked because it's just js. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/447), it seems you can also do something like this:

```js
product.category = { id: 1 }
product.save()

// Or
product.category = new Category().id = 1
product.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use typescript both
`roduct.category = { id: 1 }` and `product.category = new Category().id = 1` throw an error, you can use:

```
product.category = Object.assign( new Category(), {
    id: id,
});
```

Comment: It's absurd that this still seems the only way to update related entities without setting the whole object. Did you ever manage to find a cleaner method?

Answer (score 0):

I handle this problem by typecasting:

```
product.category = { id: 3 } as Category;
```